Why are two signals with different FFTs producing the same impulse response?
I have two different FFTs, their complex values are visualized here:

They share similar structure but they're clearly different values.
When I do the inverse FFT on them however, they both have virtually the same spatial values, the MSE between them is on the order of 1e-11:

I know that signals with different FFTs cannot have the same spatial representation, but why are they so close in the spatial domain and (at least seem to be) so different in the frequency domain? Is there something about the pattern here between their FFTs that can explain this?
For context, I'm generating the FFT in red by directly sampling a transfer function H over a range of frequency values. And the FFT in blue is generated by taking the FFT of the impulse response h produced by the strided IIR equation corresponding to that transfer function H.
When I increase the frequency sampling resolution, their difference between their impulse responses gets very small, but their frequency responses still look quite different.

There's one simple and obvious explanation: You have made a mistake somewhere. Since you do not share your data or your methodology in detail, this is hard to verify. But it certainly is the most plausible explanation.

As said in the comments, this is likely due to a miscalculation or typo somewhere in your code. Every function (for practical purposes) has a unique Fourier transform. This is an easy proof. Let's say we have two functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$, and form the function \begin{equation}h(t) = f(t)-g(t)\end{equation}
We can then say \begin{equation}H(\omega) = F(\omega)-G(\omega)\end{equation}
In your case, $h(t)\approx 0\;\forall\: t$ as 1e-11 is likely a rounding error from the IFFT function. So we can then say
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
H(\omega) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt \\ &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}0e^{-j\omega t}dt \\ &= 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
However, it doesn't look like the error between your FFTs is 0, so there is likely a typo somewhere.
Furthermore, from Parseval's theorem, we know that
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left\lvert h(t)\right\rvert^{2}dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left\lvert H(\omega)\right\rvert^{2}d\omega
\end{equation}
So if the MSE is large in one domain, and virtually 0 in the other domain, then you can be pretty sure there is just an error somewhere.

Ok yes you were right, there was a bug in my code.
I was evaluating out the impulse response of a comb IIR spatially but I wasn't evaluating it out for enough samples, which meant that I was truncating the impulse response. Let's say that I evaluated it out to N samples when the actual impulse response didn't decay to zero until M samples.
Then I tried what I thought  was an equivalent way of evaluating the impulse response by querying the comb filter's transfer function at N evenly spaced frequencies and then did the inverse FFT. But with this approach I was seeing the effects of the signal wrapping over on itself.
Then, when I increased the frequency sample resolution, it removed the wrapping issue so that when I plotted the truncated spatial regions between these two methods, they matched up. But their frequency responses still differed because the frequency response of the impulse that was evaluated spatially and truncated is basically the directly sampled frequency response convolved with a sinc.
